# Parsing file to struct in C

Tags: c, parsing, struct

I have a file with questions and answers formatted like this:

```
1;Which US state is famous for Disneyland and the film industry?;California;Washington;Florida;
```

The number(which is 1 in this case) tells us how many questions the file contains.

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct{
    char answer1[30];
    char answer2[30];
    char answer3[30];
    char question[30];

}Questions;
```

I'll use a loop to scan in the text to the struct, something like this:

```
Questions q;

for(int i = 0; i < number;i++){
    fscanf(file, ";%s; %s; %s; %s;", q.question, q.anwswer1, q.answer2, q.answer3);
}
```

The problem is that the question and answers in the file is separated with ";", how can I scan in the values in the file to the struct?

Comment: That results in undefined behaviour. Please read about pointers, arrays and dynamic memory allocation. Most good C books include examples how to read file data.

Comment: I've updated the struct, I should be able to do this without pointers, right?

Comment: Advice: use `fgets` and `strtok` instead of `fscanf``.

Comment: Ok, I'll try fgets instead.

Comment: ... and `for(int i = 0; i < number; 1; i++)` is invalid C,  it won't compile....and you need an array of `Questions`.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < number; i++).

Answer (score 3):

Take the following steps for each line of input:

- use `fgets` with a large enough buffer to read a line from the input file.  Check for a `NULL` return value to detect end of file.
- parse the line with `strchr`, `strtok` or by testing for `';'` explicitly with a `for` loop.
- for each element, change the `';'` separator to a `'\0'` and use `strdup()` to make a copy of the field value and store the pointer to the corresponding member of your structure.
- use the `Question` structure for what it is needed, and `free` the pointers when it is no longer needed,
- repeat for the next line.

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to do this with fscanf though.
Maybe like this: 
typedef struct{
 char answer1[30];
 char answer2[30];
 char answer3[30];
 char question[30];

}Questions;

fscanf(file, ";%s; %d; %d; %d;", q.question, q.answer1, q.answer2, q.answer3);

Comment: Not this way.  `fscanf` is very difficult to use correctly.  The format would be: `fscanf(file, "%*d;%29[^;\n];%29[^;\n];%29[^;\n];%29[^\n]%*[\n]",...);` or something similar, with appropriate extra arguments.

Comment: Ok, I will try fgets instead. Thanks

Comment: I don't seem to have strchr or strtok. I got the fgets working and I now got the lines to work with. I didn't understand how to change the ";" to \0. How can I do that with ";Which language apart from English is an official language of Canada?;French;Spanish;German;" for example?

Comment: `strtok` and `strchr` are standard functions declared in `<string.h>`.  Changing the `';'` at `buf[i]` is very simple: `buf[i] = '\0';`.  You seem to be lacking basic notions of C programming, I suggest you re-read your textbook or a Beginners Tutorial for the language.